# BTSTask ImportBindings

Tags: biztalk

I have a simple batch file that executes BTSTask ImportBindings on a previously exported binding file. There don't seem to be any errors thrown. The send / receive ports and orchestrations are created ok. The problem is that the orchestrations are not bound and the hosts are not set.

I've examined the binding file and it looks ok. Within BindingInfo\ModuleRefCollection\ModuleRef\Services\Service I have the orchestrations and these have Ports\Port elements which contain valid values for SendPortRef / ReceivePortRef.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this problem? As I've said. there's no error thrown at the command line when I run the BTSTask ImportBindings.

Many thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Richard but I did try importing the binding file manually through the BizTalk admin console and this worked fine.

After further investigation, my colleague (thanks Brad) discovered that the only significant difference between the binding file which was failing and a previous working version was in the  node of the send ports. It seems that I had opened the Binding File in XML Spy and hit the pretty-print button, this inserts spaces into the ordinarily messy  node and those spaces seem to cause the problem

Answer (score 1):

I've expeirienced an unrelated issue with the filter element on send ports.  It may apply to orchestrations.  In the case of the filter, the text must begin right after the element name... NO CRLF.  And the last line of the filter, the last character, must be smack up next to the closing element tag. NO CRLF!  It was frustrating.  The binding would import, but the send port would fail to start with a vague error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot a failing BTSTask ImportBindings action is to manually import the finding file. Right click on the *Applications*-node or the node of a specific application an choose *Import Bindings*. Then one usually sees the errors that probably occur when you try to bind.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Riri, import, fix the errors then reexport the binding file - you can spend hours trying to spot faults in bindings files.